# Sort order by Name collection.php (magento)

Tags: magento

I have a custom module with change the default CATALOG/RESOURCE/PRODUCT/COMPARE/ITEM/collection.php, but the line below:

`->order('ai.sort_order ASC');`

Change the order for position with attributes position, but a few of is (about 10 attributes) is just a text **(not Dropdown, Select or Price)** and cannot allow to orders correctly position iquals a product page order. (i need to leave the page to compare products in the same order from the product page of the attribute list)

how i can make this?

Answer (score 1):

To create sort by position write below code after getting product collection in **`app/design/frontend/<theme_name>/default/template/catalog/product/list.phtml`**

```
$_productCollection = new Varien_Data_Collection();
$sortedCollection = array();
foreach ($_defaultProductCollection as $key => $_product) {
    if(!isset($sortedCollection[$positions[$_product->getId()]])){
        $sortedCollection[$positions[$_product->getId()]] = array();
    }
    $sortedCollection[$positions[$_product->getId()]][] = $_product;
}
ksort($sortedCollection);
foreach ($sortedCollection as $_products) {
    foreach ($_products as $_product) {
        $_productCollection->addItem($_product);
    }
}
```

Hope it will work for you.

Comment: what I need is in the compare/item/collection.php, this list.phtml would be generated where ?? in my theme I not found list.phtml on the product page or in the compare screen, index.php/catalog/product_compare/index/

Comment: you can use this code any where after getting the productCollection object.